# pdo_sqlsrv with php 7.4 and ubuntu 20

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

When I install pdo_sqlsrv it get pdo_sqlsrv 5.9.0, I do not if it is the correct version for php7.4.

I select php version 7.4 before to run the installer with update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4

```
When the command "sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv" finish I get "successfull"
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/pdo_sqlsrv-5.9.0
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You added "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" to php.ini
```

I am enabled the extension with:

```
 extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

but the extension is not enabled, when I do php -i |grep srv I got:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_unregister_driver), /usr/lib/php/20190902//usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902//usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

It is installing the correct version of pdo_sqlsrv ?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the location `/usr/lib/php/20190902/` and confirm the extension files are available

Comment: Did you also install the ODBC driver? [See full instructions on the microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15-)

Comment: Thank you for your helps. I put extension=pdo.so before extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so and it works fine. Finally I should have put in the next order:  extension=pdo
extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_sqlsrv.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/sqlsrv.so